# Activate extension in TYPO3

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Is there a way, to activate an extension in TYPO3 without using the extension manager in the backend?

I'm using TYPO3 7.6.4 in composer mode. If I install a new extension with composer, it is deactivated by default.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer does not install the extension TYPO3 wise. It only downloads it to `typo3conf/ext`. You can read more about it [here](https://usetypo3.com/typo3-and-composer.html) if you are interested.

There is, however, an alternative to the extension manager for (un)installing extensions in TYPO3. You can run a CLI command to do so. Go to your web directory and run

```
./typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh extbase extension:install <extension_key>
```

or for the "help page" of the command:

```
./typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh extbase help extension:install
```